# How to open Safari Extension ToolbarItem popover programmatically

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, safari-extension

I want to programmatically trigger a 'click' event on my Safari Extension toolbarItem so that my custom popover appears after something happens on the webpage. I'm using the new Xcode extension IDE and have built my popover using interface builder. All of the answers on StackOverflow currently deal with extensions built in the Safari extension builder and not in the Xcode interface. For example, I have tried injected Safari JS solutions like:

```
safari.extension.toolbarItems[0].showPopover();
```

But nothing happens, and I don't think it's supposed to work when you build extensions in Xcode. I don't care whether the popover is triggered in the injected javascript or in my SafariExtensionHandler.Swift file -- I just need a way to show it without a user click on the toolbar item.

I have associated my popover with my toolbar item using the extension's info.plist which I have linked to below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxyLs.png

The extension is bundled with a native CocoaOS app, and it's constructed using the new Xcode paradigm introduced at WWDC '15 (link below). I can access the Toolbaritem in SafariExtensionHandler.Swift with this method:

```
 func getToolbarItem(completionHandler: @escaping (SFSafariToolbarItem?) -> Void) {
    SFSafariApplication.getActiveWindow {$0?.getToolbarItem (completionHandler: completionHandler)}
}
```

But the toolbarItem object doesn't seem to have a method to show the popover.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/214/

Answer (score 7):

```
SFSafariApplication.getActiveWindow { (window) in
    window?.getToolbarItem(completionHandler: { (item) in
        item?.showPopover()
    })
}
```

Comment: That's the correct answer, but the API is only available from macOS 10.14.4+

Answer (score 3):

Open the `Info.plist` of your Safari extension and locate the `SFSafariToolbarItem` key, then look for `Action` sub-key and make sure it's set to `Popover`.

Also, make sure that your `SFSafariExtensionViewController` subclass assigns the desired `preferredContentSize`.

```
import SafariServices

class SafariExtensionViewController: SFSafariExtensionViewController {

    static let shared = SafariExtensionViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        preferredContentSize = NSSize(width: 330, height: 119)
    }

}
```

Comment: That code sets up the popover size, but does not open it programmatically.

Comment: Thank you. For those who are still confused, the default value for the key "Action" is "Command", just change it to "Popover".